# Problem reading the contents of the text file and displaying it as a string

Tags: c

I have a text file named MySQL.txt having the following contents :

```
MySQL_IP:172.19.1.173
MySQL_USER:kok
MySQL_PASS:kok
MySQL_DATABASE:kok
```

I am trying to read the contents of the file using the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
FILE *fp;
char str[50000];
fp = fopen("MySQL.txt","r");
fgets(str,sizeof(str),fp);
printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

No matter how much i increase the size of the string buffer,i am provided with teh output which is :

```
MySQL_IP:172.19.1.173
```

which is just the first line...I fail to fathom the reason !!!

Answer (score 3):

There is documentation that you can use and look up easily on your favorite search engine which will tell you the answer. For example, [as described on this page for `fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html):

> The *fgets()* function shall read bytes from stream into the array
>   pointed to by *s*, until *n-1* bytes are read, or a  is read and
>   transferred to *s*, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The
>   string is then terminated with a null byte.

If you need to read in the entire file at once, use [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html) instead of `fgets()`. Unlike `fgets()`, `fread()` will not stop reading on occurrence of a newline.

If you want to process the file line-by-line, then call `fgets()` repeatedly until [`feof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/feof.html) returns a non-zero value (indicating EOF) or [`ferror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ferror.html) returns a non-zero value (indicating an error condition).

Comment: It's better to check the value returned by `fgets()`; it returns the value `EOF` if there's nothing more to be read.  This applies to all the standard input functions: check the documentation for the function you're using to see what it returns to indicate the end of the input.  After `fgets()` tells you it's finished, *then* you can use `feof()` or `ferror()` to tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` reads a line, i.e.: until the next `\n` (newline) in the text or end of file.

To read the whole file, you need to repeat the sequence until `feof` returns true.

Comment: More precisely `fgets()` reads a *line* (and stores it in a string).  (Or it reads a partial line if there isn't enough room to read it all.)

Answer (score 0):

fgets documention says :

syntex :

char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );

Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or a the End-of-File is reached, whichever comes first.
A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character and therefore it is included in the string copied to str.
A null character is automatically appended in str after the characters read to signal the end of the C string.

so here fgets only read upto 1st line 
so i suggest u to use fread()